# Can AES Encryption and RSA Digital Signature Scheme work together for file encryption?

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa, digital-signature, file-transfer

I am planning on file encryption during file transfer from physical storage to physical storage as my final year project at my high school.

My question is, can AES Encryption and RSA Digital Signature Scheme be used as file encryption? Currently I am focusing on text files (`.doc`, `.txt`).

I've got the following protocol in mind:

- the file will be encrypted using AES Encryption
- the private key from RSA Encryption will be the signature for the file
- the public key will verifies the signature during decryption

I am not sure about the bit sizes of the keys to use, either 256 bit AES and 1024 bit RSA.

Comment: See [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_encryption)

Comment: Not really a programming question, Vasanth, you might want to use http://crypto.stackexchange.com instead. As you are in high school, I'll make an exception. You are mixing a strange set of keys. Most of the time you store either symmetric or asymmetric keys. You might want to take a look at various container formats such as [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) and [(Open)PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) before continuing.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time AES and RSA are used together in the following way:

1. create an asymmetric key pair and keep the private key confidential and the public key in a trusted keystore
2. create a symmetric data encryption key and encrypt the data with it (e.g. using AES-CBC and a random IV)
3. encrypt the symmetric data encryption key using the public key of the key pair
4. create a signature with a private key (if possible, using a separate key pair), using e.g. PKCS#1 using the SHA-256 hash algorithm
5. store the encrypted data (+IV), the encrypted key and the signature

To verify

1. retrieve the data etc.
2. verify the signature using the public key from the trust store
3. decrypt the symmetric key using the private key (protected by a password, stored on an USB stick or smart card etc)
4. decrypt the data

You will need some way to store the data. It's best to use a common format for this such as Cryptographic Message Syntax. For key sizes see http://www.keylength.com/ e.g. using the NIST or ECRYPT II recommendations. I would suggest matching sizes, e.g. AES-128 bits, RSA 3072 bits and SHA-256 for the signature.